# Filteration of 0 counts in all column of metrics and add pseudo counts in remaining columns after filteration?

Tags: r, bash, shell, sh

I would like to filter out the row which have correspondence 0 counts in all columns (samples) of my count metrics.
Then I also would like to add some integers (pseudo counts) in remaining columns.
The main problem is that I have about 36 columns + 1 id, and Icant wrap this code what I have done for 6 columns for my another matrix.

```
cat matrix.txt | awk -F "\t" '{if ($2>0 || $3>0 || $4>0 || $5>0 || $6>0 || $7>0 )print $1"\t"$2+1"\t" $3+1"\t"$4+1"\t"$5+1"\t"$6+1"\t"$7+1"\t" }' > final_matrix_nonzero_1pseudoCounts.txt
```

for exp:

```
id          c1   c2  c3   t1  t2  t3
gene1       0   0     1   0   0    1
gene2       0   0   0     0   0   0  #should be removed; gene 2 rows; all columns have 0 in all sample
gene3       1   1     23   45   5   0
```

then add 1 in remaining matrix (final matrix)

```
     id          c1   c2   c3   t1  t2  t3
gene1            1    1     2     1   1   2
gene3            2    2     24   46   6   1
```

Comment: Also perhaps this could work (not tested) `awk' {for(i=2; i <=37; ++i) if($i !=0) {print; next}}' final_matrix_nonzero_1pseudoCounts.txt`

Comment: thank you akrun for your quick reply and answer.....its done by R. However, shell code is not working as you have suggested, getting error. 

Might someone fix it.

thanks once again :)

Comment: @Akurn: its data.frame and i have no character on my columns, all are numeric. by the way......i have done it..your R code is fine now. Just i have changes my input parameter in read.table.

df <- read.table("all_htseqCount_Zfish_v21.txt",sep="\t",as.is=T,row.names=1,header=T)

Answer (score 1):

In `R`, you could do

```
indx <- !grepl("id", colnames(df))

df1 <-df[!!rowSums(df[,indx]),]
df1[,indx] <- df1[,indx]+1

df1
#     id c1 c2 c3 t1 t2 t3
#1 gene1  1  1  2  1  1  2
#3 gene3  2  2 24 46  6  1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(id = c("gene1", "gene2", "gene3"), c1 = c(0L, 
0L, 1L), c2 = c(0L, 0L, 1L), c3 = c(1L, 0L, 23L), t1 = c(0L, 
0L, 45L), t2 = c(0L, 0L, 5L), t3 = c(1L, 0L, 0L)), .Names = c("id", 
"c1", "c2", "c3", "t1", "t2", "t3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Thanks you akrun but i prefer bash one liner code or something....However, The main problem is that I have about 36 columns + 1 id.

Comment: @Rupesh.  It doesn't matter if you have 36 or 44 columns.  Here, in the code, I assumed your `id` column is the first column.  You had `r` tag, so I answered a solution in `R`

Comment: Anyway...thanks man, i tried by this way and got error.

df <- read.delim("all_htseqCount_Zfish_v21.txt",header=TRUE)

indx <- !grepl("id", colnames(df))
head(indx)

df1 <-df[!!rowSums(df[,indx]),] ### error; x must be numeric
df1[,indx] <- df1[,indx]+1